# How to send notification to users?

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, notifications

I have a jobcard System where jobcards will be delivered between employees. Each Employee will have their screens open. I want to make a site which will give them notification when they will get a new job card. How may i start building it?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax and some real time server thing. Read more on "pull" and "push." This is a little bit of complicated topic. There is no clear cut answer. Read on "push" technology on Ajax. Or timely polling.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for polling. I.e. having an client-side timer that periodically asynchrony calls a server function that checks for new notifications and displays them to the end-user.

Another option would be something called [HTTP server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push), but from what I read this could be rather tricky to work on every browser and also could consume more server resources.